# Error deleting Google account from Samsung Galaxy S4

Tags: settings, samsung-galaxy-s-4, gmail, google-account, google-settings

I recently upgraded my Samsung Galaxy S4 to Android Lollipop (5.0.01).
I created a new Google account and then added it to the device; when I triee to delete the old Google Account from the device I didn’t succeed to access to the google account. I went into settings>accounts>google account, and an error popped up: "Unfortunately, Settings has stopped." Is there any other way to delete the Google account from my phone?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In case nothing else helps, you can always factory reset the device, that's gonna do the trick for sure. Keep in mind that this will delete all of your data and everything else, too, so just use this as a last resort.

The only other thing you could try to do is to delete the data of the settings/account related apps, but that's also potentially risky, so make a backup of everything first.